# How can I download .rpm file including its dependencies in Windows 10

Tags: centos, windows, rpm, dependencies, internet

I have an unnetworked CentOS PC and need to download packages for it in Windows 10 PC with internet access.
I can find and download a necessary package in rpmfind.net but it does not include its dependencies.
Can I download an RPM file and all its required dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you install WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on your Windows 10 system. Then download and install CentOS WSL from https://github.com/mishamosher/CentOS-WSL.

You can then download RPM packages and all dependencies using standard CentOS tools such as `yum-plugin-downloadonly`

```
# yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
# yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package-name>
```

You may have to add the appropriate repo details first if these packages are not in a standard enabled repo.

You can then sneaker-walk the downloaded RPMs from the download directory using a USB stick, or other approved device, to your non-networked CentOS system

Comment: Any other way? because I have trouble installing WSL2 for some errors.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Instead of using WSL2, you could install VMware Player, and create a CentOS VM.

Comment: I can't use VMWare at work. The error 'assembly not found. error code 14081' Even I cannot do it in GUI

Answer (score 1):

You could install VirtualBox or VMWare Player (free for personal use), install CentOS in either of them
then

```
sudo yum install --downloadonly what_you_need
```

Then extract the rpms from `/var/cache/{dnf,yum}` via e.g. SSH or FTP. You might need to shuffle your connection from NAT to host-only and reconnect the guest. You might also want to disable `firewalld` which is enabled by default in CentOS 8.

The you put all these RPMs into a single directory and run

```
sudo rpm -Uvh *rpm
```

---

And here's yet another alternative: find any cheap VPS hosting (E.g. [Linode](https://www.linode.com/?r=064e47ee0318ecf9288d855d48c54845e702d01a) where you can pay by hour) with CentOS and do the same.

Comment: These days one can also use `docker` as a more lightweight and easier to use alternative.

Comment: I didn't know docker works under Windows and then setting it up for inexperienced users could be a challenge.