# Can I download only already installed package? (RHEL)

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, download

The OS is RHEL 7.
Can I only download and not install a package which is already installed in this system?
I'm doing this in order to install the package to another RHEL system without internet access.

There is a package yumdownloader or yum install option --downloadonly, but it seems to work only when the required package is NOT installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yum reinstall --downloadonly package`

If you also need all the dependencies, check this question: [How can I download .rpm file including its dependencies in Windows 10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636286/how-can-i-download-rpm-file-including-its-dependencies-in-windows-10/636320#636320)