# Get a URL list of .rpm to update a package in closed network environments

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

### Background

I am running a server with RHEL 8 in a closed network environment. I can upload files to the server, but I can't use `yum update` on the server.
I want to update a specific package to the latest version. To update the package, I have to update the packages required from the updated package.

### Problem

If you can enumerate all the URLs of `.rpm` files required to update the package, I can download the `.rpm` files from the other environment and upload them to the server.

I know you can use `repoquery` to retrieve a dependency tree and the URL of the packages in the tree, but there is no RHEL environment other than the one in the closed network.

### Question

Is there any way to enumerate all the URLs of `.rpm` files required to update a specific package without a RHEL environment?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use :

```
rpm -qR package_name.rpm
```

for example:

```
rpm -qR https://vault.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/vim-minimal-8.0.1763-16.el8.x86_64.rpm
warning: https://vault.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/vim-minimal-8.0.1763-16.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 8483c65d: NOKEY
config(vim-minimal) = 2:8.0.1763-16.el8
libacl.so.1()(64bit)
libacl.so.1(ACL_1.0)(64bit)
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
libselinux.so.1()(64bit)
libtinfo.so.6()(64bit)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
rtld(GNU_HASH)
```

and after getting the packages you need to build by self the URLs

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but our RHEL environment is in a closed network and can't access to the Internet, so the answer doesn't work for my situation.

Comment: @SATOYusuke, in this command you can point to file from internet or to local file.

Answer (score 0):

This answer works perfectly: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/636320

Only instead of installing a package you do `dnf update --download-only`, copy RPMs to the destination PC and run `rpm -Uvh *rpm`.

If you keep packages synced on both devices you can do that indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I may not install additional OS-like environments (VMWare or WSL) in my Windows environment due to development environment management. Is there any way that is available on the default Windows environment?